# Usar TextChanged para sumar dos EditText, al mismo tiempo que muestro resultado de la suma en un TextView

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

### Hola buenos días, me gustaría que me dieran consejos para resolver este problema.

Estoy haciendo una app de ventas en Android con Kotlin, tengo dos EditText que expresan la cantidad de efectivo a pagar, ya sea de una forma de pago o de otra, lo que quiero es que estos dos EditText se sumen y muestren el resultado en el TextView en tiempo real, estoy implementando el método doAfterTextChanged{}
pero al momento de digitalizar una cantidad de dos o más digitos, el primer digito se suma a la cifra completa. Les muestro una foto de mi error de lógica. El text View que muestra la suma es el de efectivo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El código del método doAfterChangedText es el mismo para los dos editText

```
quantityInputOne.doAfterTextChanged {
            try {
                if (it!!.isEmpty()) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Cantidad Vacia", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    suma = 0.0
                    resultQuantity.text = "0"
                } else {
                    suma += it.toString().toDouble()
                    resultQuantity.text = suma.toString()
                    sumQuantityInputs(totalSalesText, exchangeText)
                }
            }catch (ex:NumberFormatException){
                Toast.makeText(this, "Cantidad Vacia", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                suma = 0.0
                resultQuantity.text = "0"
            }
        }
```

Gracias por su ayuda, es mi primer pregunta aqui, disculpen voy empezando en esto

Comment: Te refieres a que suma 20  +10 ?

Comment: Mas bien, que al ingresar por teclado, me suma cada numero que recibe el editText, por ejemplo tecleo el 1+0 = 11 <--ingreso el numero 10, pero el primer digito que puse el 1 también me lo termina sumando, y así pasa con todos los numero de dos cifras o más

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A mi me funciona bien este código:

```
private var resultInt: Int by Delegates.observable(0) { _, _, value ->
    tv.text = value.toString()
}

    val ed1: EditText = findViewById(R.id.editTextNumber)
    val ed2: EditText = findViewById(R.id.editTextNumber2)
    tv = findViewById(R.id.textView)

    ed1.doOnTextChanged { text, _, _, _ ->
        resultInt  =
                (text.toString().toIntOrNull() ?: 0) + (ed2.text.toString().toIntOrNull() ?: 0)
    }

    ed2.doOnTextChanged { text, _, _, _ ->
        resultInt  =
                (text.toString().toIntOrNull() ?: 0) + (ed1.text.toString().toIntOrNull() ?: 0)
    }
```

Espero que sea lo que ocupabas.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchas gracias, eres crack, es justo lo que necesitaba!!